# angularjs ng-invalid ng-repeat element

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a form which has assigned a default state of ng-valid to elements in a select dropdown list. After much research, it appears to have something to do with ng-repeat.

```
<select id="vpo_{{$index}}" name="vpo_{{$index}}" class="form-control np fs-small" 
                    ng-options="item.id as item.es for item in mainCtrl.vpo"
                    ng-model="tEl.vpo"
                    ng-required="true"
                    ng-change="taskCtrl.toggleVpo(tEl);">
                    <option value="">N.A.</option>
</select>
```

You are therefore able to submit the form with the select dropdown list remaining untouched and unselected. If, however, you select an option and then select the default value of N.A. once more the field becomes invalid and the submit button is disabled. It works!

I am therefore trying to change the class of all instances that have N.A. as their value to ng-invalid.

```
vm.taskEl.map(function(element, index) {

        if(element.vpo == 0) {
            console.log("N/A!!!");
            // class changing function goes here
        }
    });
```

I'm struggling to get the relevant element by id in order to change the class to ng-invalid. I believe it has something to do with the index of the instance. I've tried getting the index using both $index and through the map function without success...

For example:

```
document.getElementById("vpo_"+index).classList.add('invalid');
```

Comment: What happens if you change `ng-required="true"` to just `required`? `ng-required` is really intended for situations where the required status of an element is dynamic.

Comment: Hi Lex... The class remains as "form-control ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-not-empty ng-valid-required" until it is touched...